# how to pip uninstall / delete stale directories after upgrading python?

Tags: python, pip, upgrade, archlinux

In dealing with arch linux moving to `python3.8`, I dealt with needing to rebuild some packages that no longer had the expected `.local/lib/python3.x`, which revealed what I presume are no longer needed directories:

```
$ ls ~/.local/lib/python [tab]
python2.7/ python3.6/ python3.7/ python3.8/
```

I haven't found any questions that answer:

- how does one delete packages that are no longer needed after updating python (and thus `pip`)? [Bonus: without installing the previous version of python to do so.]
- should one just delete all `*/pythonX.Y` directories and stale files after a python version update, and is there a canonical list of all directories to check?

Note: admittedly this is likely purely about sanity and a compulsive nature. Nothing is going wrong having lingering `python3.6` directories around.

Comment: I would just delete the directories corresponding to the versions of the Python interpreter I don't use anymore. If I am not mistaken everything in these directories comes from `pip install --user ...` (and similar). So it should be safe to delete those.

Comment: @sinoroc thanks for the input. Indeed, all of that is from `pip install --user`. I checked more closely and noted that all of my system packages auto-moved from `/usr/lib/python3.7/foo` to `/usr/lib/python3.8/foo`.